# How to set a float number correctly for rspec/capybara/selenium according to the current locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara

I'm using rspec, capybara and selenium webdriver with firefox for RoR testing. If I set an HTML input number field in my spec, e.g:

```
find('input_selector').set('101,1')
```

It works, because I have a Hungarian environment, and the decimal separator is comma in Hungarian locale. But it doesn't work if my colleague run the test in a US environment.

How could I determine in my spec what should be the decimal separator in webdriver/firefox?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use `evaluate_script("navigator.language")` and change behavior based on the language returned.

Something else that MAY work with selenium is

```
find('input_selector').send_keys('101', :decimal, '1')
```

I haven't actually tried that on a different locale, but I believe the :decimal key descriptor should switch to the correct character for the browser.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. `:decimal` doesn't do anything, neither a dot nor a comma, simple `1011` appears in the field. I checked with `xev -even keyboard` what I see, if I press the decimal separator button and I got `keycode 91 (keysym 0xffac, KP_Separator`. So I tried also `:separator`, but it doesn't work either. :-(

Comment: @TiborNagy hmmm -- sorry about that, just realized I was testing :decimal with Chrome.  It appears to work with Chrome and legacy firefox (<48 non-marionette) but outputs nothing with latest geckodriver and firefox.  The send keys for marionette based Firefox/geckdriver apparently is still being worked on.